# Are there old versions where var assignment on declaration won't work?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, declare

`declare @x int = 5`

Is this syntax not permitted in any old versions? I think I've read this somewhere, but never had problems. Can't find anything in documentation/searching.

Comment: It's supported in every supported version of SQL Server; how old a version are you planning to be using here? If so, the real problem seems to be that someone is still using something like SQL Server 2000...

Comment: Thankfully I don't have clients with SQL 2005, so it seems I'm covered.

Comment: Considering that SQL server 2005 has been completely unsupported for 5 years, I would hope not!